# java single byte character encoding

Tags: java, c, byte

Can any one please provide me the list of "single byte character encoding" native to JAVA
or the link where I can get this?

Like

ASCII, ISO-8859-1 , ISO-8859-15 ,.... etc

Answer (score 3):

There is no such list that is exhaustive, but Wikipedia has a [list of the more common character encodings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) (though not exclusively single-byte ones).

Answer (score 2):

Here you are: [Supported encodings in Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html)

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html#charenc) what you are looking for? Otherwise, this [list](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html) lists all supported encodings.

Comment: Thnx All @Andreas_D ,@Oswald and @Jerome, but as I know there are 3 types

Comment: Thnx All @Andreas_D ,@Oswald and @Jerome, but as I know there are 3 types  1>SBCS: Single-byte character set 2>DBCS:Double-byte character set and 3>MBCS: Multiple-byte character set ,And I am only interested in the  SBCS , so how to find out them from the all your provided lists.

Comment: @Ashish From the first link in my comment:
US-ASCII, ISO-8859-1 are single byte
UTF-8 is MBCS
UTF-16BE,UTF-16LE,UTF-16 DBCS
I think you just need to know which is which. To my knowledge, there is no way for you to ask the JVM because everything is Unicode when it is used by the JVM.

Comment: @Jerome: none of the UTF encodings you list are single byte encodings.

Comment: @Mat Hit Enter before I meant to :).

Comment: @Jerome: that happens a lot in comments :-) FYI, the UTF-8 and UTF-16 variants are all variable length encodings (1 to 6 bytes per char for UTF-8, 2 or 4 for UTF-16). UTF-32 variants use exactly 32bits per char.

Comment: @Mat: Quite right, I always forget the code units can't always encode all the code unit sequence.

Comment: @Jerome, UCS-2(le/be) is the one that always encodes to two bytes per code point.  (Graphemes may require any number of code points, though.)

Comment: @Jerome..I am creating a comboBox where I need to include ONLY all the Single Byte Char Encodings..thats why i need a list ..but as you said u just need to know which is which... so any idea how to figure out that..!!

Comment: @Ashish: I'm guessing you want single byte char encoding supported by the JVM. Call Charset.availableCharsets() (available 1.4 and up) and filter out the non-SBC encodings. You should probably change your question to reflect what you actually want to do more precisely.

Comment: @Jerome..thnx I'll try to filter out the non-SBC from the availableCharset..but one last doubt..Is Charset.availableCharsets()  gives all charset native to java only?